# monoalphabetic encryption / decryption in java swing

Tags: java, swing, encryption

> step 1. Select the virtual key. (apple)
>   step 2. Deduplicate from the virtual key. (aple)
>
> step 3. The remaining alphabets are concatenated so that there is no
>   duplication from the last alphabet.  At this time, the total length is
>   26 characters. If 'z' is filled up, it starts from 'a' again.
>
> Results: aplefghijkmnoqrstuvwxyzbcd

Fixed up to step 2, and I want to use .getText() in the text field.
I do not know how to approach from step 3.
What should I do?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;

public class monoalphabetic_Cipher extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel p1, p2, p3;      // default, staging job, job selection
    private JLabel title, l1, l2, l3, l4;   // title, virtual key input, de-duplicated virtual key, encryption, decryption
    private JButton b1, b2, b3;         // Encryption, decryption, deduplication
    private JTextField t1, t2, t3, t4;
    int i,j;

    public monoalphabetic_Cipher() {

        super("monoalphabetical cipher");

        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        p1.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));

        title = new JLabel("<html><h1>monoalphabetical cipher</h1><hr></html>");
        title.setFont(new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        title.setBounds(204, 20, 175, 57);
        p1.add(title);

        b2 = new JButton("encryption");
        b2.setFont(new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        b2.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        b2.setBounds(67, 210, 119, 23);
        p1.add(b2);

        b3 = new JButton("decryption");
        b3.setFont(new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        b3.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        b3.setBounds(67, 252, 119, 23);
        p1.add(b3);

        t3 = new JTextField(20);
        t3.setBounds(260, 212, 297, 21);
        p1.add(t3);

        t4 = new JTextField(20);
        t4.setBounds(260, 254, 297, 21);
        p1.add(t4);

        p1.setLayout(null);

        t2 = new JTextField(10);
        t2.setBounds(395, 123, 128, 21);
        p1.add(t2);

        b1 = new JButton("overlap remove");
        b1.setFont(new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        b1.setBounds(264, 122, 119, 23);        
        p1.add(b1);

        l1 = new JLabel("virtual key");
        l1.setFont(new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        l1.setBounds(55, 126, 57, 15);
        p1.add(l1);

        t1 = new JTextField(10);
        t1.setBounds(124, 123, 128, 21);
        p1.add(t1);



        p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.lightGray), " selection", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 12), new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        p3.setBounds(34, 176, 184, 122);
        p1.add(p3);

        l2 = new JLabel("\u2460");
        l2.setFont(new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        l2.setBounds(230, 211, 28, 23);
        p1.add(l2);

        l3 = new JLabel("\u2461 ");
        l3.setFont(new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        l3.setBounds(230, 252, 28, 23);
        p1.add(l3);


        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.lightGray), "ready", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("맑은 고딕", Font.PLAIN, 12), new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        p2.setBounds(34, 97, 523, 69);
        p1.add(p2);
        getContentPane().add(p1);
        setSize(600,355);
        setResizable(false);                                
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
        setVisible(true);


        // duplication remove
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int vk_1 = t1.getText().length();

                Set chk = new LinkedHashSet();

                for(i=0;i<vk_1;i++) {
                    // Convert all lowercase letters to uppercase and lowercase letters
                    chk.add(t1.getText().toLowerCase().charAt(i)); 
                }
                /// Remove brackets and commas in the [result, result] format, which is the default output method of LinkedHashSet()
                String result = Arrays.toString(chk.toArray()).replace("[", "").replace(",", "").replace("]", "");

                / * With the usual replaceAll ("", "") or trim ()
                  * If spaces are not removed, use regular expressions
                  * /tText(result.replaceAll("\\p{Z}", "")); 

                if(t1.getText().equals("")) {
                    t2.setText("no input key");
                }
            }
        });

        // encryption
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            final String curString = t2.getText();

            final char startChar = curString.charAt(curString.length()-1);

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(curString);

                char c = nextChar(startChar);

                while (sb.length() < 26) {

                    while (hasChar(sb, c)) {
                        c = nextChar(c);
                    }                   
                    sb.append(c);


                    c = nextChar(c);
                }

                System.out.printf("Final String %28s has length of %3d", sb.toString(), sb.length());


            }
            private char nextChar(int idx) {
                 ++idx;
                    if (idx > 'z') {
                        idx = 'a';
                    }

                    return (char)idx;
            }
            private boolean hasChar(StringBuilder sb, char c)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); ++i) {
                    if (sb.charAt(i) == c) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        // Decrypt
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(t2.getText().equals("")) {
                    t4.setText("no input key");
                }
            }
        });
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        new monoalphabetic_Cipher();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider that char 'A' is 65, and one can use `% 26` to one's advantage.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Comment: @FelixSFD If I unlink my post and account, can I delete the question? I do not want to be exposed to anyone who is going to do this class (for that question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assumptions that: the input String is dedupped, it is of an appropriate length, the characters to add are 'a' to 'z' inclusive, that no character should be repeated, the final String should be 26 characters long, the following provides a quick solution. Additional error checking and better naming of variables is needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // the example string
    final String curString = "aple";

    // get the starting character, which is the end of the string
    // in the example, will be 'e'
    final char startChar = curString.charAt(curString.length() - 1);

    // construct our compilation; this could also be List<Character>
    //  which would make somethings easier, but would have to assemble
    //  at the end
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(curString);

    // we want the character after the one on the end of the string to start
    char c = nextChar(startChar);        

    // we want 26 total entries
    while (sb.length() < 26) {

        // we cannot append a character that already exists, so spin
        // until we find one not in the compilation
        while (hasChar(sb, c)) {
            c = nextChar(c);
        }

        // we now have the one we want, so append it
        sb.append(c);

        // we know we need at least the next character after the one we
        //  just appended, so get it and loop; loop will terminate if
        //  we've added enough
        c = nextChar(c);
    }


    // display the result
    System.out.printf("Final String %28s has length of %3d", sb.toString(), 
            sb.length());
}


private static boolean hasChar(StringBuilder sb, char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); ++i) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static char nextChar(int idx)
{
    ++idx;
    if (idx > 'z') {
        idx = 'a';
    }

    return (char)idx;
}
```

Output:

> Final String   aplefghijkmnoqrstuvwxyzbcd has length of  26

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. However, the following exception handling error occurs.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: Final String curString = "aple";
I want to work with textfield.getText () instead of the above statement.

Comment: It is certain it does not handle anything but ASCII characters in the String between 'a' and 'z' as noted in the assumptions.

Comment: So, when I receive text input in a field, should I convert it to ASCII code?

Comment: In the String field, charAt() is not available and an error appears.

Comment: I would convert the code in `main` to a method that accepts a `String` (e.g., `padWithCharacters(String input)`. Then you can call the method with the value of the `.getText()`. However, you must ensure the input String is valid (e.g., not empty, dedupped, etc). As noted, error checking is left as an exercise to the reader. I do not understand what you mean `.charAt()` is not available.

Comment: Fixed to full source code. I would appreciate it if you point out which part is the problem.

Comment: You have `final String curString = t2.getText();` Print the value of `curString` at this point. I do not see where t2 has its text value updated. Again, *you must ensure that the value of curString is not empty* (or add logic to the `startChar` so that it is set to 'z' if `curString` is empty).

Comment: 't2' prints the deduplication result for the value entered at' t1'.

In the source code that you provide, get the result of 't2' again with .getText(). 'CurString' is not empty because it receives the value of 't2' textField.

Comment: Well, if the problem is that `curString.length() - 1` is returning -1, then the issue must be with how curString is being set. I'd move the variables for curString and startChar into the `actionPerformed()` method. Also, given how you are using them, they need not be final.

Comment: Thank you very much.I've moved the variables you mentioned to me in actionPerformed.
May I ask you one more question?
How is it effective to approach decoding methods?

Comment: You should pose your decoding question as a new question. There is insufficient information in this question to understand the decoding, so you'll need to augment the requirements. Good luck! If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it.